# TLS Data Address the Same in All Threads

Tags: assembly, linker, gdb, glibc, thread-local-storage

I traced `glibc-2.27` using `GDB`. At line `178` in `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/getsysstats.c`, there exists a `thread local storage` access, as shown below:

```
while (l < re && isspace (*l))
```

IIUC, `isspace()` seems to access a **table** *mapping* `ASCII` characters to symbol type to, quickly, determine if the current character is space or not. This table seems to be a `TLS`. The relevant disassembly is as follows:

```
0x7f8f9ef480de <__GI___get_nprocs+318>  mov    0x2cbd1b(%rip),%rax        # 0x7f8f9f213e00                                                                        
0x7f8f9ef480e5 <__GI___get_nprocs+325>  mov    %fs:(%rax),%rdi
```

`rax` contains `0xffffffffffffff98`, which, IIUC, means that the **address of the table**, for *each thread*, is calculated using the following equation:`$fs_base + 0xffffffffffffff98`. When I use this equation to find the table address for each thread, they all return **the same** value, `0x00007f8f9732b82c`. This is shown below:

```
(gdb) thread apply all x/2x $fs_base + 0xffffffffffffff98

Thread 47 (Thread 22457.22471):
0x7f8f75dfc698: 0x9732b82c  0x00007f8f

Thread 46 (Thread 22457.22470):
0x7f8f768fd698: 0x9732b82c  0x00007f8f

Thread 45 (Thread 22457.22469):
0x7f8f773fe698: 0x9732b82c  0x00007f8f

Thread 44 (Thread 22457.22468):
0x7f8f77eff698: 0x9732b82c  0x00007f8f

Thread 43 (Thread 22457.22467):
0x7f8f80a53698: 0x9732b82c  0x00007f8f

Thread 37 (Thread 22457.22465):
0x7f8f81c55698: 0x9732b82c  0x00007f8f

Thread 36 (Thread 22457.22464):
0x7f8f82456698: 0x9732b82c  0x00007f8f

Thread 35 (Thread 22457.22463):
0x7f8f8e6b0698: 0x9732b82c  0x00007f8f

Thread 34 (Thread 22457.22461):
0x7f8f8f480698: 0x9732b82c  0x00007f8f

Thread 33 (Thread 22457.22460):
0x7f8f94824698: 0x9732b82c  0x00007f8f

Thread 32 (Thread 22457.22459):
0x7f8f9649f698: 0x9732b82c  0x00007f8f

Thread 31 (Thread 22457.22458):
0x7f8f96ea0698: 0x9732b82c  0x00007f8f

Thread 30 (Thread 22457.22457):
0x7f8fa2570a18: 0x9732b82c  0x00007f8f

Thread 29 (Thread 22457.22466):
0x7f8f81454698: 0x9732b82c  0x00007f8f
```

I thought that `TLS` is **exclusive** to *each* thread, but, here, **all** threads use the **same** variable at `0x00007f8f9732b82c`. Why is this the case? It seems that the linker *recognizes* the variable is `read-only` and *saves* some space?

Comment: Verify `fs_base` gives different value in each thread. I think gdb may substitute `$fs_base` before it does the `thread apply` so it uses the current thread's value for all threads. Switch threads manually and check that way.

Comment: I checked that. They are **different**. What you are saying is true for `$fs`, *not* `$fs_base` (which was introduced in `GDB 8` to address the problem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've shown that each thread has a *different* pointer variable, in TLS storage at
`0x7f8f75dfc698` vs.
`0x7f8f768fd698` etc.

The fact that they're all pointing to the same table is completely normal, unless you've used [`uselocale(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/uselocale.3.html) to have different locales in different threads.

I think glibc has static constant (`.section .rodata`) char-map tables for different locales, and it sets a pointer to the right table based on the locale.  Duplicating the whole table for every thread would be very inefficient, wasting more L3 cache footprint.  If it was going to do that, you'd expect the whole table to be right there without a level of indirection.

Have a look at how glibc implements functions like `isupper()` - by indexing an array of character-attribute flags, and checking a certain bit in that array element.  (i.e. every array element is a bitmap of flags).

https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/ctype/ctype.h.html and related .c files in the same directory.

Comment: What you suggest is **reasonable**. But why should the tables be defined *per-thread* (and then be mapped to the **same** location)?!

Comment: @TheAhmad: Because locale stuff is per-thread like I mentioned in my answer: one thread can be using a utf-8-based locale while another is using 8-bit turkish or something. POSIX.2008 `uselocale(3) - set/get the locale for the calling thread` makes this even more clear than `setlocale`.  Or different locales can have different rules for toupper / tolower even for UTF-8.  e.g. Turkish is a classic example of many kinds of werdness, including toupper or tolower on an ASCII-range character producing a non-ASCII character, unlike for English.

Comment: So, you're saying that `locale` stuff is per-thread, but it has **some duplicate** data, such as the **mapping table**. They are **all** defined per-thread, but the linker decides to save some space using a **single** copy of the *duplicate* data. But the *non-duplicate* portion (e.g., those **exclusive** to Turkish) will be managed, *exclusively* (i.e., will **not** be shared). Right?

Comment: @TheAhmad: I think it's the other way around.  There is a single global copy of the Turkish table, and a single global copy of the French table, and so on (loaded into memory by mmap when the process starts, not linked in).  Each thread has, in its thread-local storage, a pointer to whichever table it intends to use.  If Thread A changes its locale from Turkish to French, it simply changes its thread-local pointer to point to the (global) French table instead.

Comment: @TheAhmad No, Peter is saying that there's one copy of the "C" locale data, and one copy of the "UTF-8" locale data, and one copy of the Turkish locale data.  If all threads are using the same locale then all the thread locale pointers will point to to same locale data.  There's no linker magic going on here.  The C library has just set the locale pointers to the same value. The locale pointers themselves are in thread local storage, but the locale data they point to is in normal static storage.

Comment: @RossRidge Aha! Thanks! Your comment was *enlightening*! (also `Nate`'s comment)